# Order of images loaded with AsyncTask changes when scolling in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm using an AsyncTask to load images into my ListView. However when I run the app, the order of the images changes when I scroll. I suspect that the getView() method might be at fault. But I can't find a way to fix this.

Being relatively new to Android, I can't explore much options either.

Here is my code:

DisplayPlacements.java

```
package com.example.android.areainfo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class DisplayPlacements extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;

    private String[] imageURLArray = new String[]{
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7315/9046944633_881f24c4fa_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3777/9049174610_bf51be8a07_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7324/9046946887_d96a28376c_s.jpg",
            "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2828/9046946983_923887b17d_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3810/9046947167_3a51fffa0b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3773/9049175264_b0ea30fa75_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3781/9046945893_f27db35c7e_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5344/9049177018_4621cb63db_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/9046947621_67e0394f7b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5457/9046948185_3be564ac10_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3752/9046946459_a41fbfe614_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7403/9046946715_85f13b91e5_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7315/9046944633_881f24c4fa_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3777/9049174610_bf51be8a07_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7324/9046946887_d96a28376c_s.jpg",
            "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2828/9046946983_923887b17d_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3810/9046947167_3a51fffa0b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3773/9049175264_b0ea30fa75_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3781/9046945893_f27db35c7e_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5344/9049177018_4621cb63db_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/9046947621_67e0394f7b_s.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5457/9046948185_3be564ac10_s.jpg",
            "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3752/9046946459_a41fbfe614_s.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7403/9046946715_85f13b91e5_s.jpg"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_placements);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPlacements);
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.row, imageURLArray);
        listView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
}
```

activity_display_placements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_placements"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.areainfo.DisplayPlacements">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listPlacements">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testImage"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.areainfo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by User on 30-Jan-17.
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] imageURLArray;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                        String[] imageArray) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, imageArray);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        imageURLArray = imageArray;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        String imageURL;
        ImageView imageView;
        Bitmap bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.imageURL = imageURLArray[position];
        new DownloadAsyncTask().execute(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder> {

        @Override
        protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //load image directly
            ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];
            try {
                URL imageURL = new URL(viewHolder.imageURL);
                viewHolder.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("error", "Downloading Image Failed");
                viewHolder.bitmap = null;
            }

            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (result.bitmap == null) {
              //  result.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.postthumb_loading);
            } else {
                result.imageView.setImageBitmap(result.bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: use `Picasso` http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: please add first line get view 

        String mImageURL =  this.getItem(position);
        viewHolder.imageURL = mImageURL ;//imageURLArray[position];
then replace second line  while adding image URL into viewholder

Comment: The items of your listview get recycled/reused when scrolled. If you had read this site a bit you would encountered this a hundred times. Nearly every programmer stumbled over this. So google and search. There are so many ready to use examples for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use RecyclerView instead. It is not the main problem here but recyclerview is a more optimized way of populating lists.

You can find a good example [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial)

and to load images use an image loading library like [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
it is much easier to do things in this way.

you can find a good complete example [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/image-loading-recyclerview-picasso.html)

Comment: Much better than what I had in mind. Used Picasso, works like a charm!